# Geolocation in a List Controller?

Tags: apex, visualforce, geolocation

I've successfully used geolocation in a list controller:

```
public class NearbySiteProgramListCon {
// ApexPages.StandardSetController must be instantiated
// for standard list controllers
public ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon {
    get {
        if(setCon == null) {
            setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(
                [SELECT Name, Start_Date__c, End_Date__c, ID FROM SiteProgram__c
                Where End_Date__c > Today AND
                DISTANCE(Location__c, GEOLOCATION(42.301165, -71.057052), 'mi') < 200
                Order by Name]));
        }
        return setCon;
    }
    set;
}
```

When I try to get more general in a new function, I get the following error:

> Error: Compile Error: unexpected token: 'lat' at line 40 column 54

Trying the "{!lat}" instead of just "lat" didn't work either.

Here's the function.  I want to be able to refresh the list for different regions via commandLinks in the Visualforce page.

```
public void getLocalSites(Decimal lat, Decimal lon, integer dist) {

setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(
                [SELECT Name, Start_Date__c, End_Date__c, ID FROM SiteProgram__c
                Where End_Date__c > Today AND
                DISTANCE(Location__c, GEOLOCATION(lat, long), 'mi') < 20   //line 40 is here
                Order by Name]));

}
```

Does the Geolocation function not take variables?  Is there something wrong with trying to reset the list controller?  I can write multiple functions with the distance and coordinates hard-coded, but I'd prefer not to.

**Edited to Add**

Here is the dynamic string I ended up using:

```
String query = 
'SELECT Name, Start_Date__c, End_Date__c, ID From SiteProgram__c WHERE End_Date__c > Today' + ' AND ' +
'DISTANCE(Location__c, GEOLOCATION(' + +lat.format()+','+lon.format() + '), \'mi\') < ' + dist + 
' ORDER BY Name';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Binding a variable requires a colon to start the binding. The correct syntax for your function would be:

```
public void getLocalSites(Decimal lat, Decimal lon, integer dist) {

setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(
                [SELECT Name, Start_Date__c, End_Date__c, ID FROM SiteProgram__c
                Where End_Date__c > Today AND
                DISTANCE(Location__c, GEOLOCATION(:lat, :long), 'mi') < 20   //line 40 is here
                Order by Name]));
}
```

However, a quick test suggests that you can't bind variables that way. Instead, you'll apparently need to build a string dynamically:

```
String query = 'SELECT ... WHERE ... DISTANCE(Location__c, '+lat.format()+','+long.format()+') < 20 ...';
```

Comment: Building the string dynamically worked.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

Just a footnote - bind variables in GEOLOCATION are coming in Summer 15
https://developer.salesforce.com/releases/release/Summer15/queries

Answer (score 1):

Wow - I actually found documentation of this...
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=custom_field_geolocate_overview.htm

Says:  Apex bind variables aren’t supported for the DISTANCE or GEOLOCATION functions
...

Use a database query like this one instead

```
double latitude = 10;
double longitude = 20;
double distance = 30;
Database.query('SELECT ID, Name, Location__latitude__s,Location __longitude__s FROM Party__c where '+ 'DISTANCE(Location__c,GEOLOCATION('+latitude+','+longitude+' ),\'mi\') < '+distance);
```

Consistency is boring ;-)